# Navigate to pages in different folders

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I use this html code to navigate to JSF pages:

```
<a href="NewCustomer.xhtml">New Customer</a>
```

This JSF code works fine

```
<h:outputLink value="NewCustomer.xhtml" >
    New Customer
</h:outputLink>
```

But this is not working when I have pages in different folders.

How I can navigate between pages in different folders?

I get this result when I click on the link:

http://localhost:8085/Crm_site/Dashboard.xhtml

I'm navigated here:

http://localhost:8085/customers/Customers.xhtml

But it should be here

http://localhost:8085/Crm_site/customers/Customers.xhtml

Comment: But what **does** happen? ww3? What is generated client side? 'Not working' is not as a developer should report something

Answer (score 1):

add your contextpath before page name

```
#{request.contextPath}/customers/Customers.xhtml
```

or you can navigate from backing bean using external context

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url)
```